# dexguard: encryptclasses AND encryptstrings?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, dexguard

Dexguard:

Does it make sense to use the "-encryptstrings" command for a specific class when already using the "-encryptclasses" command for this class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are obfuscation techniques, combining layers of them indeed makes reverse-engineering more difficult than just applying a single technique.